# How to use signal to execute any function with arguments?

Tags: c++, qt, function, animation

Suppose I have a `QPropertyAnimator` animating (moving), say, a button - slightly to the left over the course of 10 seconds.

When the button reaches its destination on the other side of the window it should change its text to "banana" using the `QLineEdit::setText()` function.

**If the `QLineEdit::setText()` function is issued directly after the animation start;**

```
QPropertyAnimator *animator = new QPropertyAnimator(someButton, "pos");

animator->setDuration(10000);
animator->setStartValue(*current position of the button*);
animator->setEndValue(*current position of the button with x-100*);
animator->start();

QLineEdit::setText(QString("Banana"));
```

The text changes before it has the chance to start moving. Luckily, `QPropertyAnimator` emits a signal when the animation is completed - aptly titled `finished()`.

**One would like to just be able to:**

```
connect(animator, SIGNAL(finished()), someButton, SLOT(setText("Banana")));
```

But since you can't pass an argument to a slot that won't work.

**How do I change the text after the animation is complete without creating different "proxy" functions (slots) to do it without arguments?**

Comment: If you're using C++11, you could achieve this with lambdas. There's an example here: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#Connecting_in_Qt5

Comment: Use need to use C++11 lambdas or auxiliary slots, there's no direct way to bind argument values to the slot call as you're trying to.

Comment: Where would I "put" the lambda in the above example - how would I use it? EDIT: Isn't this pretty important functionality? Are people doing the whole thing in a much better way that I'm missing entirely?

Comment: @Quoi There isn't a way of doing it other that using an auxiliary slot or C++11 lambda.  It's not that functionality is missing, it's that it is syntactically more verbose that what you would seem to prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already others told, you should use lambda, in your case,

```
    connect( animator, &QPropertyAnimator::finished, [&]()
    {
        m_lineEdit->setText( QString("Banana") );
    } );
```